# java print out a double array

Tags: java

i have an array with some double value inside:

```
private double speed[] = {50, 80, 120, 70.3};

public void printSpeed() {
    for(int i = 0; i<=speed.length-1; i++ ) {
        System.out.println(speed[i]);
    }
}

output 
50.0
80.0
12.0
70.3

wanted output
50
80
12
70.3
```

How to do print the exactly string of the array?

Comment: System.out.println(speed[i]).toString().replace(".0","") ?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67144-removing-the-zero-after-the-decimal-point/page__view__findpost__p__434542?s=747a3ccc50326ef03a71c91684c84055

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing to note to start with: the final value will *not* be exactly 70.3, as that can't be exactly represented in a `double`. If exact decimal values are important to you, you should consider using `BigDecimal` instead.

It sounds like you want a `NumberFormat` which omits trailing insignificant digits:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Consider specifying the locale here too
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.#");

        double[] speeds = { 50, 80, 120, 70.3 };
        for (double speed : speeds) {
            System.out.println(nf.format(speed));
        }
    }

}
```

(As an aside, I would *strongly* advise you to keep the `[]` for array declarations with the type information - `double[] speeds` instead of `double speeds[]`. It's much more idiomatic Java, and it puts all the type information in one place.)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", speed[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < speed.length; i++ ) {
    long l = (long)speed[i];
    if(l == speed[i]) {
        System.out.println(l);
    } else {
        System.out.println(speed[i]);
    }
}
```