# Showing Inputted Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need a little help about showing all inputted arrays.

```
float[] month; 
month = new float[12];     

for (int counter=0; counter<12; counter++) {         
    float revenueMonths = Float.parseFloat(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Revenue month of " + (counter + 1)));
    month[counter] = revenueMonths;        
    totalRev = totalRev + month[counter];                        
 }
```

As you can see from my code, it is asking the user to input the revenue of each month.
The value of months for revenue is not declared, it will be declared by the user inputs.

So, if a user inputs each month revenue as:

```
month 1 : 100 
month 2 : 100 
till 12 : 100
```

I want to print out the revenues of each month

```
month 1 : 100 
month 2 : 100
m 3 : 100 
till 12 : 100
```

How do I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java print out a double array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046818/java-print-out-a-double-array)

Answer (score 0):

This will print 1 based array index and revenue per month on separate lines. It will a different starting string for the last month as you would like. You would run this after your existing for loop.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < month.length-1; counter++) {
    System.out.format("month %d : %f\n", counter+1, month[counter]);
}
System.out.format("till %d : %f\n", month.length, month[month.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all the data in the array month, why not just print them out?

```
for (int i = 0; i < month.length; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Month " + (i + 1) + ": " + month[i]);
    }
```